# Using wget with Streamcloud and pages where you have to wait

Tags: bash, scripts, wget

I'm new to bash scripting and as I heard of "wget" I decided to write a script to download just the .mp4 file from a streamcloud (or whatever) link.

I use it normally like:

```
wget -q -O - http://somelink.com | grep keyword
```

But the problem that I'm having is that I'm getting the source from the site where I have to wait a few seconds until I "go to the video", and that's obviously not where I can find the mp4 file link. So I'd like to know how could I get the source of the page you get to after the waiting, where you can actually watch the video and whose source contains the mp4 link (then I'd be able to grep it).

I can actually get the mp4 link manually, but I would just like to automate it through a shell script.

Thanks a lot! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the wget output into a file and look at the html to see how they are implementing the timeout and redirect. There are several techniques that might be being used. For example, the simplest is a line like this in the head of the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://newurl/">
```

This makes a browser go to the new url after 2 seconds. You need to use a tool like sed to extract the url and then run wget again on the new url.

More complicated solutions involve javascript.